# Calculating the transfer function and bode plot

Tags: bode-plot

What is the transfer function and bode graph when k=0 and k=1?

[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this and prev questions u asked give the transfer function in answer.
[image]

k=0 is slightly less than -20dB or 0.1 , k=1 slightly less than +20dB or x10 with B=10

And flat 0dB gain in the middle, k=0.5